# PHP's dom->createTextNode escapes some characthers

Tags: php, xml, dom, escaping

I am using dom->createTextNode() in PHP. I see that it automatically escapes characters e.g /"" etc. According to the PHP's manual this is a standard behavior.

Is it possible that it doesn't escape any characters?

Thanks.

Comment: You might be doing something wrong. It's not escaping anything for me. Paste some code.

Answer (score 3):

If some characters are not escaped, you might not get a valid XML file, in the end.

If you don't want any character to be escaped, maybe using [`DOMDocument::createCDATASection`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php), to get [CDATA sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) in your XML file, could help.

Though, note that you will get that kind of things *(well, CDATA sections)* in your XML :

```
<tag><![CDATA[<greeting>Hello, world!</greeting>]]></tag>
```

Comment: This only works if you saveXml(), what to do when you use saveHTML() ?

Answer (score 2):

If you can avoid the escape sequences by creating a DomDocumentFragment node and appending raw text with the appendXML() method:

```
    $rawXMLNode = $domDoc->createDocumentFragment();
    $rawXMLNode->appendXML("<tag>text</tag><tag2>text2</tag2>");
    $someNode->appendChild($rawXMLNode);
```

However I don't think you can necessarily access the DOM of this raw text without reloading the document. Also some characters are still not allowed in. I needed to do some string processing to insert some php into an html document using this method:

```
    $elem = $domHtml->getElementById('header');
    $newElem = $domHtml->createDocumentFragment();
    $newElem->appendXML('<div id="header"><?php include("templates/header.html"); QQQ?></div>');
    $elem->parentNode->replaceChild($newElem, $elem);
    $filedata = $domHtml->saveHTML();
    $filedata = str_replace('QQQ', '?', $filedata);
```